# Discover Python dummy threads responsible code

Tags: python, multithreading, celery, python-multithreading

Recently I've started to see that threads named Dummy-%d pop upped in my python program (a celery based application).

The application maintains connections to RabbitMQ, Redis, Zookeeper, and MongoDB servers. All interactions are by standard libraries.

From the code [documentation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1f21eaa15e8a0d2b0f78d0e3f2b9e5b458eb0a70/Lib/threading.py#L1275-L1281), I learned that a Dummy thread class represents threads not started outside the threading module, such as directly from C code.

```
# Dummy thread class to represent threads not started here.
# These aren't garbage collected when they die, nor can they be waited for.
# If they invoke anything in threading.py that calls current_thread(), they
# leave an entry in the _active dict forever after.
# Their purpose is to return *something* from current_thread().
# They are marked as daemon threads so we won't wait for them
# when we exit (conform previous semantics).
```

How can I detect such code places, especially if they are coming from a C code?

Comment: I know this is very old question. Did you find any answer? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No. I didn’t find.